# Is it possible to decouple this Matrix A to matrix multiplication of two matrixs B and C?

Tags: matrix

[image]

I want to decouple this matrix A into two matrixs B and C, with A=B*C. And B is functions of r, C is functions of n. Is it possible or not? Can I use Mathematica to do this?
Any help or advise is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: This almost does it {{a, b}, {c, d}} /. Solve[{{1/r, 1/mu}, {mu/r^2 n, -3/r}} == {{1/r, 1/mu}, {mu/r^2, -3/r}}.{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {a, b, c, d}] Can you tweak the form of the B matrix to find a form that eliminates that mu and r in the c position of C without introducing mu or r in any other position?

Comment: @Bill Thank you very much! As you mentioned above, C from your code is functions both of r and n, and it is not  what I want to get. If anyone can get B which is only dependent of r and C which is only dependent of n, I will appreciate!

Comment: This seems more like a math question rather than a Mathematica question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be unrelated to Mathematica.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a Mathematica issue but a mathematics issue. That it is formulated in terms of Mathematica is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for Mathematica.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, correcting a typing error in the matrix leads to a different conclusion: Eigenvalues as well as determinant factorize, which points to solubility, but still, I haven't found the matrix factors.

The correct matrix is

```
a = {{1/r, 1/μ[r]}, {μ[r]/r f[n], -(3/r^2)}};
```

Where

```
f[n] = n(n+1)-2
```

The determinant is

```
Det[a] // Factor

(* Out[194]= -(3 + f[n])/r^2 *)
```

and the eigenvalues are

```
ev = Simplify[Eigenvalues[a], {r > 0, μ[r] > 0}]

(* Out[200]= {-((1 + Sqrt[4 + f[n]])/r), (-1 + Sqrt[4 + f[n]])/r} *)
```

Both oviously factorize as required. Hence it cannot be ruled out from this consideration that the matrices of the OP do exist.

Comment: Isn't it a little simpler in this case to look at the determinant? (+1 either way)

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze Thanks. I find the eigenvalues of "a" are functions both of r and n after using you code. Then you mentioned "a[r,n]==b[r].c[n] " is impossible, why?

Comment: @tanghe2014 Because the eigenvalues of a poduct of matrices is equal to the product of these eigenvalues.

Comment: @Michael E2 yes, you are right.